# how to play mp4 video file in html5

Tags: html, video, struts2

I am new in **struts2**.

I am uploading video file in system Directive using struts2 but when I want to access uploaded content in Html5 file to play the uploaded video file then i cant able to play.
my current uploded directory in D:/dk. but when i put this path in html code then it doesn't work.

**Action Class**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.FileSizeLimitExceededException;
import org.apache.struts2.util.ServletContextAware;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class FileUpload1 extends ActionSupport implements ServletContextAware {

    private File userImage;
    private String userImageContentType;
    private String userImageFileName;
    private ServletContext context;

    public String execute() {
        try {
            String path = context.getInitParameter("FileUploadPath");
            FileInputStream in = null;
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            in = new FileInputStream(getUserImage());
            String destFileName = path;

            File destFile = new File(destFileName);
            destFile.setReadable(false);
            if (!destFile.isDirectory()) {
                destFile.mkdir();
            }
            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destFile+"\\"+userImageFileName));
                         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int c;
            while ((c = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer,0,c);

            }

            if (null != in)
                in.close();
            if (null != out)
                out.close();
            return "success";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            addActionError(e.getMessage());
            return "input";
        }
    }

    public File getUserImage() {
        return userImage;
    }

    public void setUserImage(File userImage) {
        this.userImage = userImage;
    }

    public String getUserImageContentType() {
        return userImageContentType;
    }

    public void setUserImageContentType(String userImageContentType) {
        this.userImageContentType = userImageContentType;
    }

    public String getUserImageFileName() {
        return userImageFileName;
    }

    public void setUserImageFileName(String userImageFileName) {
        this.userImageFileName = userImageFileName;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext arg0) {
        context = arg0;
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>         
            <param-name>FileUploadPath</param-name>
            <param-value>D:\Dk</param-value>        
  </context-param>
   <filter>
                      <filter-name>f1</filter-name>     
                        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>

      </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>f1</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="html5lightbox.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <a href="C:\Users\asus\Desktop\video1.mp4" class="html5lightbox" title="Altoopa">
                <img src="images/Playing-Altoopa.png"/>
            </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that how to put the path of uploaded video in `<a href....>` tag. my uploaded file location is `D:/Dk/dd.mp4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser only accesses content exposed by the web app, not arbitrary locations on the server's hard drive–imagine what it would mean to provide carte blanche access to the server?!

Instead, you need to stream it from an action, e.g., using the `stream` result type, or configure your server to allow access to specific asset directories, etc.

The href of your anchor tag needs to point to the action, and provide enough information to retrieve the file. You could provide a file name via a URL parameter, use a REST-style parameter, etc.

If you'll be writing directly to the response (IMO a bad idea) you'd need to set the content type and possibly things like length etc. I think the `stream` result type would be better, though.

---

Unrelated, but your action class is doing too much; the file IO work should be done somewhere besides your `execute` method, like in a service or utility class.

Comment: tnx for ur reply. i got ur idea.sir plz give me some code for streaming the video file and where i have to put to play....

Comment: @user3143376 It's the same as streaming an image back (except the content type is different). Read the docs for the `stream` result type.